# C# Android:How to detect swipe gestures for individual views, such as, buttons, text views, whole activity etc

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, touch, gesture

I'm trying to develop an app, where there will be 3-4 buttons. On every button, I want to detect swipe right/left/up/down gestures. but I want the functionality
of these gestures different for each button. I'm not getting that how to do that. Please somebody help. currently, I'm able to successfully detect swipe
gestures on whole layout/class, but unable to do so for specific views such as buttons, textviews etc.

Comment: follow my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273025/genericmotion-action-down-not-firing/41280040#41280040)  it should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

// Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Instantiate the gesture detector with the
    // application context and an implementation of
    // GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
    // Set the gesture detector as the double tap
    // listener.
    mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
        float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll: " + e1.toString()+e2.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onShowPress: " + event.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Rahul, Actually this is java code, I've already tried it, but the implementation is somewhat different in C#. so, I'm looking for example in C#(xamarin)